# Excel Highlight Duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have two columns in Excel 2010. Column B has 180,000 positions and column A has 30,000 positions.

I want to find, and highlight, the items that are repeating from column B, in column A. So I need to find the matching column A values in the column B.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your question was difficult to understand so I edited it for clarity. If I inadvertently changed the meaning, please [edit] to explain better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlighting duplicate column-pairs in Excel](http://superuser.com/questions/486695/highlighting-duplicate-column-pairs-in-excel)

Comment: Which column do you want to highlight values in? A or B?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, highlight the columns and go to

*Home - Styles - Conditional Formatting - Highlight Cells Rules - Duplicate Values*

This will highlight any duplicate values between the two columns (and within the columns) in whatever way you select.

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle this using the Power Pivot Excel Add-In. You can use it's CALCULATE function to find duplicates, missing values and much much more.

Javier Guillen wrote a couple of excellent blog posts on these very topics:

http://javierguillen.wordpress.com/2012/10/15/profiling-data-in-powerpivot-detecting-duplicates/

http://javierguillen.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/profiling-data-in-powerpivot-comparing-two-tables/